# $.get() and $.post() in MVC app works fine in local Cassini webserver but when published into IIS 7.5 it doesn't work anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I'm actually stuck on this MVC application and can't find out the cause.

The code works fine in local Vis Studio 2013 Cassini webserver.

Hence when I type the URL in the browser: "/Customer/EnterCustomerDetails"
then I'm displayed a simple form, a DIV tag containing status message "Loading..." and after 5 seconds some data via EF is returned due to the $.get() script that gets executed.

However, when I publish the same code into IIS 7.5 running inside Windows 7 Ultimate, then all I see is the form and only the div tag that displays the message "Loading..." but no data is displayed and it seems the $.get() is not working in the full blown IIS and neither is $.post().

Where am I going wrong? Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**"EnterCustomerDetails.cshtml"**

```
@model P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel
@using P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.Models

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EnterCustomerDetails</title>

    @*BELOW Weve IMPORTED the 3 important JQuery LIBRARIES, since we want to use the $.get() AJAX method*@

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form id="frm1">
            Customer Code:- @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerCode)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Customer.CustomerCode) <br />

            Customer Name:- @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Customer.CustomerName) <br />
            <input type="button" value="Submit via true AJAX" id="btn1" onclick="SendData()" />
        </form>

        <div id="status"></div>
        <table id="tbl">
            <tr><th>Customer Code</th><th>Customer Name</th></tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#status").text("Loading..."); //Add STATUS MESSAGE "Loading..." to DIV. Must use ".text" and NOT ".val"

            //Making a CALL to the "GetCustomers" ACTION within the "Customer" CONTROLLER and Results returned will be in "BindData"
            $.get("GetCustomers", null, BindData);

            // The "GetCustomers" ACTION will return the JSON data into this JavaScript function
            function BindData(customers) {

                var tbl = $("#tbl");

                for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                    var newRow = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + customers[i].CustomerCode + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + customers[i].CustomerName + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";

                    tbl.append(newRow);
                }

                $("#status").text(""); //REMOVING STATUS MESSAGE to EMPTY
            }

            function SendData() {
                $("#status").text("Adding data via ajax..."); //Add STATUS MESSAGE "Loading..." to DIV. Must use ".text" and NOT ".val"

                var frm = $("#frm1").serialize();

                $.post("Submit", frm, BindData);

                $("#Customer_CustomerCode").val("");
                $("#Customer_CustomerName").val("");
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**"CustomerController.cs"**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.DAL; //"CustomerDal" in here which derives from "DbContext"
using P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.Models; //"Customer" class in here
using P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.ViewModel;

namespace P10LearnNewMVCWithEF.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //Below is our NEW Simplified ACTION that will simply display our Enter Customer Details UI
        public ActionResult EnterCustomerDetails()
        {
            CustomerViewModel objCustomerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
            objCustomerViewModel.Customer = new Customer(); //This code by SHIV is pretty useless

            //NOTE - WE'RE NOT RETRIEVING ANY DATA FROM DATABASE ANYMORE! as we'll do that with "GetCustomers()" ACTION
            return View("EnterCustomerDetails", objCustomerViewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer();

            obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["Customer.CustomerCode"]; //"name" is used on Server-side. "id" is used in Client-side.
            obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["Customer.CustomerName"];

            CustomerDal dal = new CustomerDal();

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Let's INSERT the new Customer into DB via EF
                dal.Customers.Add(obj);

                dal.SaveChanges();
            }
            List<Customer> customersColl = dal.Customers.ToList<Customer>(); //Return all data from tCustomer via EF

            return Json(customersColl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //make sure you say customersColl AND NOT “customersColl”
        }

        //Below: "GetCustomers()" ACTION will be called by $.get() and simply returns a Collection of JSON data
        public ActionResult GetCustomers()
        {
            CustomerDal dal = new CustomerDal();
            List<Customer> customerscoll = dal.Customers.ToList<Customer>();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            return Json(customerscoll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Try using `$.get('@Url.Action("GetCustomers")', null, ...` so that you urls are constructed correctly.

Comment: are you putting it not in the root dir of a website but to a relative dir ?

Comment: Use the Chrome Developer Tools Network panel to look for an error in the request response.  Consider using $.ajax instead of get so that you can provide a .fail handler to at least provide feedback.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made the change as suggested but still no luck.

Comment: @BJSafdie As your suggestion I used $.ajax() with error attribute to display a dialog box with a message. The returned result due to the error tag caught the following error: [object Object]. Does this mean that it successfully made a call to the ACTION but it returned an empty object? I'm fairly new at this.

Comment: @DanKuida Tried both, deploying to the root of IIS as well as to a specific port of IIS and results are still the same.

Comment: [object Object] just means that it tried toString on an object that it did not have a better way to convert to a string.  You need to use a debugger to break in the .fail and look at the returned error.  Also, as I said before, using Chrome's Developer Tools Network panel (or Fiddler) will let you see the raw request and response.

Comment: @BJSafdie As per ur suggestion, looking into Chrome dev tools shows the following, which I believe it means that it tried to do a GET but something went wrong calling the ACTION inside the Controller: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Request URL:http://localhost/P16RootIIS/Customer/GetCustomers
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Usually, in the response (look at the preview in Chrome Tools) you will be able to see a stack trace to get an idea of where the error occurred server-side.  If it is in your controller or other code you wrote, then set a breakpoint and debug.  If not, then it is likely routing or some other action in the pipeline before the request handler is assigned.  You will need to adapt your debugging to the situation.

Comment: @BJSafdie Looking at the Response per your suggesstion shows the following.  It works fine in local Cassini but not IIS obviously. How can I overcome this situation. Error generated was:  [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user &#39;IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0&#39;.]

Comment: That sounds like the identity in your IIS app pool is not authorized for database access.  Either assign a new identity that has permission,  or grant access to the identity you are using.

Comment: @BJSafdie Thank you so much BJSafdie! Your suggestion worked and I learnt a few things on the way too! Thanks to all the other guys for giving me some tips also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so that you can mark it as answered.

That sounds like the identity in your IIS app pool is not authorized for database access. Either assign a new identity that has permission, or grant access to the identity you are using.